# ¿Cómo aumentar la recompensa a mi pregunta?

Tags: discusión, recompensas

Hace tiempo hice una recompensa a [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35272/como-recuperar-todos-los-archivos-gridfs-en-mongodb), pero desafortunadamente no ha podido ser respondida. ¿Cómo puedo aumentar la recompensa para atraer aun más la atención?

Comment: Espera a que se termine la recompensa, luego podrás agregar otra.

Comment: La quiero acumulativa, es posible. ?

Comment: Creo que solo se puede en el primer día. Tendría que conversarlo.

Comment: @Rastalovely Cada vez se duplica, primero son 50, luego hay que transferir otros 100, entonces 200... Pero si ya lo perdiste no es reembolsable, y no es acumulativa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que la respuesta a tu pregunta está aquí: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/344171)

> Can I raise my bounty?
>
> You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time. Moreover, any user may have at most 3 concurrent bounties at a time.

Lo que traducido sería:

> ¿Puedo incrementar mi recompensa?
>
> Tu puedes ofrecer tantas recompensas en tu pregunta como quieras. Sin embargo, **sólo una recompensa podrá estar activa en una pregunta al mismo tiempo**. Además, cualquier usuario puede tener como máximo 3 recompensas a la vez.

Por lo tanto la respuesta sería no, no puedes poner varias recompensas a la vez en una misma pregunta. Tendrías que esperar a que la recompensa acabara para añadir una recompensa nueva (la cual será como mínimo, mayor que la recompensa actual).